# Avoid generation of default setter getter

Tags: scala

I added my own getter and setter to a variable:

```
class Person{
    private var age = 0
    def currentAge = age
    def currentAge_=(age: Int) = this.age = age 
}
```

Looking at compiled version gives:

```
public class Person implements scala.ScalaObject {
    private int age;
    private int age();
    private void age_$eq(int);
    public int currentAge();
    public void currentAge_$eq(int);
    public Person();
}
```

I want to avoid automatic generation of default getter and setter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
private[this] var age = 0
```

so that `age` is only visible to the instance.